# Selectize.js - Populate select element with result of ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, selectize.js

I have a selectize.js select, that is working. When a new tag is created, an AJAX request is sent to the backend, a new tag is created and returned and then I intent to populate the select element with the result.

I know the ajax is working, (the alert in the code below returns the correct values and the database populates) but it is not being show on the front end select and I have to relog the page.

```
    $('#tags').selectize({
              delimiter: ',',
              persist: false,
              create: function(input) {
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: '/api/newtag',
                      data: { name: input, type: null},
                      success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                          alert("Created: " + result['id'] + " / " + result['name']['en']);
                          return {
                              value: result['id'],
                              text: result['name']['en']
                          }
                      },
                      error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                          alert("Status: " + status + " Error: " + error)
                      },

                  });
              }
          });
```

Comment: Read the [documentation on the `create` option](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md).

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you. The ajax function should return the required object.

Comment: I actually changed it to a call back. It works now but enters it twice

Comment: Ah, but that's progress. Can you update the question with your current code?